# Select * from table where date = ... and after

Tags: mysql

I have a table. In this table there is a column with dates. This column indicates the registration date.

So, i need a query in order to select all entries from table for which the registration date is for example from 10 of May 2014 and after.

Can i do this somehow like:
SELECT * from table
WHERE datetime from'2014-05-210%' till today
?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What data type is datetime column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just use the `>=` operator

```
SELECT * from table WHERE datetime >= '2014-05-21'
```

or

```
SELECT * from table WHERE datetime >= '2014-03-21' AND datetime <= '2014-04-21'
```

For a range, you can also use the `BETWEEN operator.

```
SELECT * from table WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2014-03-21' AND '2014-04-21'
```

Comment: I'd prefer (`>= ... AND .. <`) over `BETWEEN`, especially for datetimes.

Comment: I agree. `BETWEEN` does `>= .. <=`, as I also wrote in my second snippet, but in practice you will usually have `>= .. <` for datetimes, when you select two date they should be inbetween. I personally never use `BETWEEN`, but I thought I should add it for compleness.